# Plotting SVD components produces cone-like shape

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis, svd

[image]

I'm using SVD on sparse timeseries data. I have unique stores and up to 84 time points for each store. I have reduced the timepoints to 3 dimensions. I'm trying to see if I can eventually cluster stores according to their time series. I realize that using SVD for this is not an optimal approach and I'm sure there are better ones. If anyone has advice about what to try, I'd love input, but I'm mostly curious as as to what phenomena would produce shape like this in SVD.

Answer (score 0):

This is typical for SVD and PCA when the data is not really a good fit for the method.

The first component is largely capturing the variance/magnitude in your data. This is "correct", and it is not necessarily a good idea to remove this effect. Its just not what you expected when you were thinking of 2d toy examples with Gaussians - you may want to accept that the magnitude of your data is the most important factor.

Comment: Thanks so much! Are there examples for when the magnitude takes over like this? My data probably comes from a Poisson. Im wondering if it’s possible to do a transformation on the original data to correct for this.